# Android Java, Checking if DB SELECT statement has returned a value

Tags: java, android

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private SQLiteDatabase database; 
public Database(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version)
{
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    database = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE USERDATA(name varchar(21), password varchar(13), email varchar(55), score int)");
}

public ArrayList<User> getResults()
{
    ArrayList<User> x = new ArrayList<User>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USERDATA", null);
    if(cursor.getCount()==0)
    {
        cursor.close();
        return x;
    }
    
    int nameindex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    int passwordindex = cursor.getColumnIndex("password");
    int emailindex = cursor.getColumnIndex("email");
    int scoreindex = cursor.getColumnIndex("score");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        User u;
        u = new User(cursor.getString(nameindex), cursor.getString(passwordindex), cursor.getString(emailindex), cursor.getInt(scoreindex));
        x.add(u);
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    cursor.close();
    return x;
}
public void clearData()
{
    database.execSQL("delete from USERDATA");
}

public void insert(String n, String p, String e, int s)
{
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO USERDATA(name, password, email, score) values('"+n+"','"+p+"','"+e+"','"+s+"')");
}

public void update(String e, int s)
{
    database.execSQL("UPDATE USERDATA SET score = '"+s+"' where email = '"+e+"'");
}

public boolean select(String e)
{
    boolean flag = false;
    database.execSQL("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERDATA WHERE email = '"+e+"'");
    return flag;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE USERDATA");
    onCreate(db);
}

public Cursor rawQuery(String query, String[] strings) {
    return null;
}
```

}

^That's the database class. So I used the:

```
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERDATA WHERE email = ?";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {x});
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 // do your stuff
            }
```

which you told me, in my main class. So to get it working, I gotta do it that way so when Cursor != null, return smth else and not null lol.
No matter what now, it'll always return null.

Comment: what's the type of database?

Comment: Sorry, SQLiteDatabase

Comment: You should either delete your own question, or post your answer and accept it so that others who might have the same problem can be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) or query api instead of executeSQL which doesn't return anything as its of void type. Try something like:

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERDATA WHERE email = ?";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, new String[] {e));
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
     // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: It's giving me error on the db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {e}); because it's asking to create a method "public Cursor rawQuery(String query, String[] strings)" in my Database class.  If I create it, it's working fine but what different values can it return so I can make it working with my check ? 'cause return null is the only thing that's working atm -.-

Comment: It's SQLite database api which you should have if you have another class. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) page for details of api provided by SQLite Driver.

Comment: Do you mind if I show you my complete Database class ? 'cause I've checked that page but these cursors are a headache

Comment: Sure go on.. paste it in question..

Comment: Okay... I did it (I did paste).

Comment: instead of `return null;`, write `db.rawQuery(query, strings);` in your rawQuery method.

Comment: Now it says that the Cursor method needs a return :D ("This method must return a result of type Cursor")

Comment: I found another way with my already existed getresults ;) I vote your answer as the right one 'cause you "opened my eyes" haha :D